# IsDaylightSavingTime strange behaviour

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc

Why the method IsDaylightSavingTime() returns an apparently wrong value for a specific hour range? To be unambiguous i start from a UTC date. The time `new DateTime(2016, 10, 30, 0, 59, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)` is the last minute of DST for WEST. Indeed in WEST it gives 2 hours of offset (2.59 am), while a minute later there is an offset of 1 hour (2.00 am). But then why:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(
    new DateTime(2016, 10, 30, 0, 59, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time")
).IsDaylightSavingTime()
```

returns false?!

This method returns false starting from `new DateTime(2016, 10, 30, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)` (but why?), the second before, `new DateTime(2016, 10, 29, 23, 59, 59, DateTimeKind.Utc)`, it returns true.

The TimeZoneInfo methods seems to work:

```
    var thisIsTrue = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time").IsDaylightSavingTime(new DateTime(2016, 10, 30, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));

    var thisIsFalse = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(new DateTime(2016, 10, 30, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time")).IsDaylightSavingTime();
```

Comment: I ran this code in VS 2015 Community, and all 3 dates you listed return true for me. Could you describe in detail your environment?

Comment: I am running this code on VS 2015, my time zone is W. Europe Standard Time, is there something else you could need?

Comment: Not sure. I did find '.IsDaylightSavingTime()' will return false if the date is not formatted correctly or is ambiguous, but I dont notice a mistake in your code that would cause this however. Is there a larger code snippet? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isdaylightsavingtime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: this is probably the reason! instead the TimeZoneInfo method "resolves" the ambiguity evaluating directly the UTC datetime, I try to look better in this direction, thanks for now

Comment: If you run 'var isDaylightSavingSUpported = TimeZoneInfo.Local.SupportsDaylightSavingTime' on your machine, is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casey-obrien is right in his comment. The reason is that once translated into my local timezone, all the hours between 2.00am and 2.59am became ambiguous, since they occur twice: once before the dst ends and once after. That's why the method returns false.

Casey, if you write your comment as answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In 2016 Daylight saving time in europe ended on 30th October. So as far as I can see IsDaylightSavingTime() returning false is totally correct. In 2015 daylight savings ended on 25th October and if you fill in that date and 24th October 23:59 you will get the same results.

Regarding the time.

The use of `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` will return a DateTime (10/30/2016 02:59:59) where the DateTimeKind is `Unspecified` which means it will call `TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime` and return False.
While passing an UTC DateTime to `TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime` like so:

```
TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(new DateTime(2016, 10, 30, 0, 59, 59, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

Will cause different kind of calculation to be done, namely:

```
Boolean isDaylightSavings;
GetUtcOffsetFromUtc(dateTime, this, out isDaylightSavings);
return isDaylightSavings;
```

My guess is that calculation has some differences because of the implicit conversions vs the explicit conversions. DateTime is kind of annoying with these things and that's why I tend to lean more towards [Noda time](http://nodatime.org/) these days.

Comment: @MassimilianoCarosi I updated my answer to include the time problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

The `ConvertTimeFromUtc` method returns a `DateTime` type which has a different implementation of `IsDaylightSavingTime` method from using `TimeZoneInfo` type.

- [DateTime IsDaylightSavingTime() Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isdaylightsavingtime(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [TimeZoneInfo IsDaylightSavingTime() Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382013(v=vs.110).aspx)

Try the following code instead...

```
var date = new DateTime(2016, 10, 29, 23, 59, 59, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var foo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time").IsDaylightSavingTime(date);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't answer his question. It's exactly the same as he is doing right now.

Comment: this doesn't answers, but points out that the TimeZoneInfo method works fine, instead, i have added further information to the question

Answer (score 0):

If the time zone represented by the TimeZoneInfo object does not support daylight saving time, the method always returns false. A number of time zones, including Utc, do not observe daylight saving time. To determine whether a time zone supports daylight saving time, retrieve the value of its SupportsDaylightSavingTime property.

[check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isdaylightsavingtime?view=net-6.0)